# Sci-fi or horror, guess from Mars

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, space, soft-sci-fi

When I was young, I saw a movie from space. I remember just this scene:
bloody red sand, astronauts building a white oxygen tent. Inside, they take off their helmets, and from behind the tent window jumps up a skeleton. An astronaut lady starts to scream.
For sure it was a really old movie, because of common spacesuits.

I'm finding probably 8 years.

Comment: What does "I'm finding probably 8 years" mean? You watched it 8 years ago, or you've been searching for 8 years? What about "common spacesuits" - can you describe what you mean and how it implies the movie must be really old? Also, what is a "really old" movie to you - 1930s? 1950s? 1970s?

Comment: "When I was young, I saw a movie *from* space." You must have had an amazing childhood. :)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [Moontrap](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/), 1988?

There's a scene where a NASA astronaut (Walter Koenig) and a female alien are in spacesuits, set up a white igloo air shelter, and are then confronted by a dead Bruce Campbell popping up in a window.

It's on [Youtube](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiox_HsqsL5AhX3FzQIHVUhBBwQtwJ6BAguEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhITc3tAbHNs&usg=AOvVaw3tOuTZHfknZjHyAfH7n9Zp).  Shelter sequence at 1:05.

It's a bad movie.

Comment: Having watched *Babylon 5*, I can't see a Walter Koenig character as anything other than a slimeball now.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, one of Koenig's reasons for taking that role was so people would stop seeing his characters as Chekov, so... mission accomplished?

Comment: Bonus points for using some 14/2 Teck cable as the alien tentacles, that saved the budget right there.