# Movie where AI or robot wears skin of person and asks for spare parts

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, robots

I have a distinct image in my head of a horror Sci fi movie from when I was little. I don't know specifics but I vaguely remember a scene where this group was hiding in this room where this killer robot thing was trying to get in. It was wearing the face of a dead character and when the other characters asked what it wanted, it started listing off body parts. One of the characters was like "it wants spare parts".

I started googling around because I brought it up to friends and family and no one knows what I'm talking about.

*Moontrap* (1989) popped up when I looked today, but I'm not sure it's that movie. Does a scene like that exist in that movie?

If anyone has other ideas for what the movie (or even show) might be, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, can you tell us anything more about the setting of the film. For example, what kind of physical location did the scene you've described take place in? Someone's house. A spaceship? Somewhere else? And was the film obviously set in the distant future, or was it in a more contemporary setting?

Comment: [Moontrap](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266597/sci-fi-or-horror-guess-from-mars/266598#266598)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is ***[Virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_(1999_film))*** (1999).

> *Virus* is a 1999 American science fiction horror film directed by visual effects artist John Bruno and starring Jamie Lee Curtis, William Baldwin and Donald Sutherland. Based on the comic book of the same name by Chuck Pfarrer, it tells the story of a ship beset by a malevolent extraterrestrial entity that seeks to turn humanity into cyborg slaves.

The film involves an extraterrestrial, electrical lifeform which flies into the Mir space station in Earth's orbit and is transmitted from that to a Russian research vessel in international waters. It then takes over everything computerised on the ship -- including the machine shops, which it uses to fashion a variety of robots, some vaguely humanoid, some insect-like -- and kills a quarter of the crew, causing the rest to abandon ship.

A week later, the deserted ship is boarded by the mostly American crew of a tugboat, who hope to salvage the vessel, but they start getting killed off by the robots, which now have human body parts grafted onto them. The alien also turns some of its human victims into living cyborgs, under its control.

At around an hour into the film, the alien is attempting to force its way into the communications room, where the surviving crew of the tugboat are holed up. They manage to communicate with it using a computer terminal in the room, and the following discourse takes place:

> RICHIE MASON: What do you want from us?
>
> ALIEN: Viscous neurological transmitters, oxygenated tissues, aponeurus superiorus papelbrai...
>
> STEVE BAKER: "Superior..." What the hell is that?
>
> NADIA VINOGRADOVA: It's part of an optic nerve.
>
> KIT FOSTER: What?
>
> RICHIE MASON: **Spare parts. It wants us for spare parts.**

You can view a brief clip of the scene in question at around the 1:48 mark in the trailer below.

Comment: @Dosco Jones - Thanks for attempting to add a better video clip, but I changed it back to another trailer. The clip you added did show more of the scene in question, however, I noticed that while it's viewable to Internet users in the US, it isn't viewable in any of the European countries I checked using my VPN. The trailer is viewable in both and I think it's better to use a clip which can be viewed by as wide an audience as possible.

Comment: For site users in the US, Dosco Jones found this [alternate video clip](https://youtu.be/ppfnHlRju7Y?t=10) which shows more of the scene in question.

Comment: Just to note, this appears to have been referenced in the 2014 episode of Doctor Who, "[Deep Breath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Breath_(Doctor_Who))" (Peter Capaldi's first outing). The Cyborg was after optic nerve there too, but from a T-Rex in Victorian London.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is it! That was such a quick response, I'm blown away haha. 